# How to manage RSA keypair in TPM2 using Linux

Tags: linux, rsa, tpm

I'm trying to use TPM 2.0 chip in my laptop to manage new pair of RSA keys and create a CSR on top of new private key but when I list certificates managed by my TPM, I got only keys labeled as public and don't know, how to get URL to my private key which I want to use for CSR generation.

I used following procedure:

````
#generate rsa key:
p11tool --login --so-login --generate-rsa --bits=2048 --label=dave4 "$token"```

#list my certificates:
p11tool --list-all ""
````

But all certificates URL I got when I try to list them are labeled as public:

```
pkcs11:model=NPCT75x;manufacturer=Nuvoton;serial=0000000000000000;token=dave4;id=%34%39%30%66%65%35%65%34%30%30%34%64%65%33%65%30;object=myfirstkey;type=public
```

and list priv keys does not return any object:

```
p11tool --list-privkeys pkcs11:model=NPCT75x;manufacturer=Nuvoton;serial=0000000000000000;token=dave4
No matching objects found
```

Do you have any idea how to get list of private keys URL or another way how to generate new rsa keypair in order to create CSR afterwards?

Thanks.

Comment: Which PKCS#11 module are you using for this?

Comment: I use tools from this repo: https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-pkcs11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually these objects are created with the CKA_PRIVATE attribute, indicating that they're hidden from the normal list – you must specify **`--login`** and provide the token PIN in order to see them.

```
p11tool --login --list-privkeys 'pkcs11:model=NPCT75x;manufacturer=Nuvoton;token=dave4'
```

But if the PKCS#11 module has a private key stored, then the URI for public and private halves almost always has exactly the same `id=`, so you can just edit the URI by hand. The private key might have a different `object=` label (so remove that parameter), and it will of course have `type=private`.

For example, this should be a working URL:

```
pkcs11:model=NPCT75x;manufacturer=Nuvoton;serial=0000000000000000;token=dave4;id=%34%39%30%66%65%35%65%34%30%30%34%64%65%33%65%30;object=myfirstkey;type=private
```

or even:

```
pkcs11:model=NPCT75x;token=dave4;id=%34%39%30%66%65%35%65%34%30%30%34%64%65%33%65%30;type=private
pkcs11:model=NPCT75x;token=dave4;object=myfirstkey;type=private
```

Note that *tpm-pkcs11* is still far from complete. There have been many API-related bugfixes recently (some of them were merged literally yesterday).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually it successfully work also in case you don't change type=public to type=private and I don't really understand it, but this was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Yes, when you're signing or decrypting, the library already knows that it requires a specific object type, so you don't even need to add `type=` at all – it will be replaced by the library anyway. It's only needed when using generic functions such as reading or deleting.